# How to translate content in category.php or index.php with qtranslate?

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I was wondering how to translate content under `index.php` (or `category.php` with qtranslate?).

I'm using twenty twelve theme.

My code on `index.php`:

```
<?php
/**
* The main template file.
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
* @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
$page_id = 1500;
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>
<section id="last-articles_homepage">
<h1>Latest News</h1>
...
```

I would like to translate the content inside the `<section>` and `<h1>` tag for example in french.

Comment: Have you read the instructions for the plugin? I've never used it, but the instructions suggest it's as simple as visiting a page/post with a language argument on the URL, eg: `?lang=en` or `?lang=fr`...

Comment: So you want to translate this static text: 'Latest News'?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż : indeed. I've tried [en:]Englishtext[fr:]frenchtext instead of the static text, but it won't work. (sorry for my poor english)

Comment: The `:` should be before the lang, not after. 
Ex : `[:en]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most correct way to do this would be to use WordPress translations.

You should replace this static text with:

```
<?php _e('YOUR TEXT', 'your_text_domain'); ?>
```

And add text domain to your theme.

More on this topic: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

### You can also...

... use `qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage` function.

Just use it like so:

```
<?php echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<!--en:-->Latest News<!--:--><!--fr:-->dernières Nouvelles<!--:-->'); ?>
```

Comment: it does not work... when i put it, i see the both language text in the same page :/ even if the other text block are displayed in the right language (because there are editable via the wordpress admin panel)

Comment: Which solution are you using? Post your code, pls

Comment: <?php
    ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php 
    $page_id = 1500;
    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    
    ?>
    <section id="last-articles_homepage">
    <h1>Derniers articles<?php echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<!--en:-->Latest News<!--:--><!--fr:-->dDerniers articles<!--:-->'); ?></h1>

Comment: It should be: `<h1><?php echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<!--en:-->Latest News<!--:--><!--fr:-->dDerniers articles<!--:-->'); ?></h1>`

Answer (score 10):

This solution worked for me

```
<?php echo __('[:fr]Plus[:en]More'); ?>
```

Note : the " **:** " is before the language, not after

Comment: IMHO best answer. Short, simple and works fine.

Comment: Yes best answer, worked fine for me with qTranslate-X 3.4.6.8

Comment: According to the FAQs this is a recommended way of doing it. https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for a related problem of mine in a [Qtranslate Support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-qtranslate-writing-html-in-the-template-file-with-multiple-languages) forums:

```
<?php if(qtrans_getLanguage() == "fr") : ?> <h1>This is French</h1>
<?php endif ?> 
<?php if(qtrans_getLanguage() == "en") : ?> <h1>This is English</h1> 
<?php endif ?>
```

I hope it would work for you! :)

Comment: **qtrans_getLanguage** is deprecated use **qtranxf_getLanguage** instead

Answer (score 1):

I got this from [WP Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/translate-direct-html-from-the-php?replies=8) and it worked for me.

```
<?php _e("[:fr]Les réseaux sociaux[:en]Social Media[:]"); ?>
```